# Error building IOS App after installing pod file

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I was installing the [pod](https://github.com/devxoul/Carte)

```
pod 'Carte'
```

The library also wanted me to paste this line at the bottom of my pod file:

```
post_install do |installer|
  pods_dir = File.dirname(installer.pods_project.path)
  at_exit { `ruby #{pods_dir}/Carte/Sources/Carte/carte.rb configure` }
end
```

After running `pod install` the library was installed, however, I was getting warning messages in the terminal about

> always embed swift standard libraries

I searched up and found a few Solutions. and found that settings them to $(inherited) worked for most people. I did this, cleaned and pod install again and nothing changed. I also saw someone changing

> always search users paths

to $(inherited) too, so did this. The error is still there.

On building my project. I also get the error

> Cycle inside APPNAME; building could produce unreliable results

To which I found changing to the legacy build system would do the trick, however, I do not want to change to the legacy build system. I do not understand why the messages have appeared. I have removed `pod 'Carte'` from the pod file and the line they wanted me to paste and I still get the error after installing again. I also tried deleting both the pod file and pod lock file, deleting the `xcworkspace` file and reinstalling the pod file and still, the error remains. Does anyone have a solution to this? Thank you.

from inspecting that error I found this:

> error: Cycle inside TARGET; building could produce unreliable results.
>   Cycle details:
>   → Target 'TARGET' has compile command with input '/Users/andrewharris/Desktop/TARGET/TARGET/TARGET/Notifications/AcceptedRemovedRequest/AcceptedRemovedCell.xib'
>   ○ Target 'TARGET' has target dependency on Target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension'
>   ○ That command depends on command in Target 'TARGET': script phase “[Carte] Pre Script”

I think that somehow `Carte` has not uninstalled in some way?

Comment: Yikes! You might try `pod deintegrate`, create a new podfile without Carte, and then `pod install`.

Comment: @MikeTaverne thank you for the suggestion. I tried this and it ended up making more errors after cleaning and building. I have failed with nonezero exit code and the same as before: Cycle inside TARGET; building could produce unreliable results

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this error by inspecting it a little closer. Inside the error:

> Cycle inside TARGET; building could produce unreliable results

It told me it had something to do with the target `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension` I looked in the target and found in build phases there was still `[Carte] Pre Script` and `[Carte] Post Script` and so I deleted both. I also deleted the target and recreated it just in case. I also did the same in my AppName Target and deleted both the Pre and Post script. Afterwards, I cleaned and ran the project to which it succeeded.